# Is there any way to convert Single array to one hot encoding?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have taken as input string convert in array but now I want this array to in one hot encoding to run in the model.

```
  from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
  Smi = input("Enter Smile")
  inn = [Smi]
  details = np.array(inn)
  details = details.reshape(1,-1)
  encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
  encoder.fit(X)
  me = encoder.transform(details).toarray()
  me

  ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

I am also sharing my google colab for better understanding.

[Code done on google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h1C2_nbncwelc8KmD28NA8bZAho3yb6c?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
# Let fit an enocode first
X = np.array([":)",":(",":!",":}",":|"]).reshape(-1,1)
print (X)

encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
encoder.fit(X)

Smi = input("Enter Smile")
# Assuming that you typed :!
details = np.array([Smi]).reshape(1,-1)
print (encoder.transform(details).toarray())
```

Output:

```
[[':)']
 [':(']
 [':!']
 [':}']
 [':|']]
Enter Smile:!
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
``
```